# Enter value in row based on rows above and below it (multiple rows above and below)

Tags: excel, rows, infinite-loop, vba

I'm trying to identify batches of rows in my spreadsheet by looking at rows above and below it, sometimes over 20 above and below. I have my spreadsheet sorted so all policy numbers are grouped together and what i want is a macro that will look at all the rows that share that policy number and see if the range of rows contains a certain value in at least one of the rows in a different column.

So one column has policy numbers and one has Risk ID. I'm looking to highlight batches of matching policy numbers (theyre already sorted by policy number and therefore are grouped)if at least one of the rows in the batch contains the value "BINT" in the adjacent column to policy number.

Here's what ive tried. I named the range of Policy numbers in the first column PolicyNumbers. The macro will run the first value correctly and output RED (as desired) into the third column, but after that it seems to going into an infinite loop of some sort and then excel crashes. I cant figure out why

```
Sub fixit()
    Dim rcell As Range
    Dim counter As Integer

    For Each rcell In Range("PolicyNumber")
        Do Until rcell <> Range("A" & rcell.Row + 1)
            rowset = rcell.Row + 1

            If Range("Q" & rcell.Row) = Range("Q" & rowset) Then
                Range("R" & rowset) = "RED"
            Else
                Range("R" & rowset) = "GREEN"
            End If
        Loop
    Next rcell
End Sub
```

Comment: ignore the dim counter as well

Comment: it will probably be more efficient if instead of `Range`, you use the `Cells` method taking two integers for the row and column

Comment: where is `rowset` declared/`Dim`-ed?

Answer (score 0):

If I have gotten this right then you can do this with a formula:
Assuming data up to row 100 (to be adjusted), put this in column C for example:

`=SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$100=A2)*($B$2:$B$100="bint"))`

This will put `1` in **all** rows in C where A=x if there is **any** row where A=x and B = "bint".

Comment: I tried it but it only returned zero's for each cell.

Comment: Put the formula as given in `C2` and copy it down. Check if the `A2` in the formula changes on each row (which is right).

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub test()

Dim PNR As Integer
Dim RowN As Integer


PNR = Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

RowN = 2

For Each Cell In Range("A2:A" & PNR)

    If Cells(RowN, 1) = Cells(RowN + 1, 1) Or Cells(RowN, 1) = Cells(RowN - 1, 1) Then
    Cells(RowN, 2).Value = "Green"
    Else
    Cells(RowN, 2).Value = "Red"
    End If

RowN = RowN + 1
Next Cell

End Sub
```

I believe this is doing what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Looks like it is omitting the last instance of a policy number as the condition `Is it the same as below` is not true. I'll look to an edit

Comment: just about to try it!

Comment: i got an overflow error. I think this is because PNR and RowN are integers which can only be assigned a value of 32000 or something like that and my sheet is a little over 40000. I'll try changing the variables to long?

Comment: It just made all the cells "Green". What i think your code is missing is that after it realizes its within a particular batch of rows where the values in column A are the same, it looks into another column to see and is looking for a particular value ("BINT"), if it find at least one of these rows haser that value in the particular column it gives ALL the rows in this batch the value of "Green" in a third column.

Answer (score 0):

This managed to work when i inserted a blank row between each new policy batch

```
    Sub test()

Dim PNR As Long
Dim RowN As Long
Dim str As String
Dim str1 As String

 str1 = "Green"
 str = "BINT"

PNR = Worksheets("Page1_1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

RowN = 2

For Each Cell In Range("A2:A" & PNR)

    If Cells(RowN, 1) = Cells(RowN + 1, 1) Or Cells(RowN, 1) = Cells(RowN - 1, 1) Then

        If Cells(RowN, 17).Value = str Or Cells(RowN - 1, 18).Value = str1 Then
            Cells(RowN, 18).Value = "Green"

        Else
            Cells(RowN, 18).Value = "Red"
        End If
    End If

RowN = RowN + 1
Next Cell

End Sub
```

Comment: This macro won't run past row 21821. Is there some limit on Long variable?